# Connecting a Honda 7000iS portable generator to a transfer switch

Tags: generator, transfer-switch

I recently purchased a Honda EU7000iS generator ([manual](http://cdn.powerequipment.honda.com/pe/pdf/manuals/00x31z376011.pdf)) to power our house when the power goes out. The house came with a transfer switch but I'm unsure which cord to buy to connect the two. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I've attached a picture of the instructions manual for the transfer switch.

[image: Transfer Switch Instructions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Good news: you can use this generator with this transfer switch

The good news is that the EU7000is, luckily, is a *floating neutral* generator, so it can be used with simpler transfer switches, such as your "select circuit" switch, or breaker interlocks without violating the NEC's grounding and bonding provisions.  (Many jobsite generators have *bonded neutrals* as per the OSHA rules on worksite use, but this means that they need to be used as *separately derived systems*. This, in turn, requires a transfer switch which switches the neutral wire over so that you don't put the two neutral-ground bonds in parallel inadvertently, which'd cause merry havoc with stray neutral currents and even GFCI tripping.)

### ...but the cord you'll need is kind of odd

The problem is that you'll basically need an adapter in order to plug your generator into your house, as your transfer switch has a 50A, California Standard twistlock inlet which requires the correct connector (the inlet's a CS6375 and the mating cord cap's a CS6364), while your generator has a NEMA L14-30R on it.  Such a thing [does exist](https://www.homedepot.com/p/AC-WORKS-Transfer-Switch-Temp-Power-Adapter-L14-30P-30-Amp-4-Prong-Locking-Plug-to-CS6364-50-Amp-Locking-Female-Connector-ADTEL1430/302002602), or you could use a length of 8/4 outdoor *cordage* (such as SOOW), a NEMA L14-30P, and a CS6364 cordcap to fabricate your own cord.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! With the adapter you mentioned, can I buy a L14-30P cable like [this](https://www.amazon.com/L14-30P-L14-30R-Generator-Extension-Cords/dp/B07V4D5J6L/ref=sr_1_5?dchild=1&keywords=30+Amp+4-prong+NEMA+L14-30P&qid=1607131633&sr=8-5) to pair with it? Side question: would 40 ft length be OK, or should I try to stick to a shorter cable?

Comment: @MikeBuss yeah, you'd plug the adapter in at the transfer switch, and 40' should be fine, you don't want the generator right up against the house for fire and CO safety reasons

Answer (score 0):

See where it says "NEMA 14-50"? That's the designation of the cord cap that you need for the generator. You also need cord rated for 50A, so depending on length, at least #6, 3 conductor + ground (so 4 "wires" in the cord). You can usually find those at RV supply stores.

Comment: Uh...that's not a NEMA 14-50... (I *wish* there was a NEMA L14-50 to be fair...anyone care to petition NEMA to adopt the California Standard 50A twistlocks?) (also, bad Generac!)